# New model to convert two bits of data to each other

Tags: cryptanalysis

In during of my study between Geometry and Cryptography I found a new model to convert any two data to each other in other word let we have two data $A$ and $B$ such that each other consist of $n$ bits. There exit a invertible transformation $T_{(A,B)}$ such that $T_{(A,B)}(A)=B$.
I modeling this transformation in geometry (permutation is a particular of this model). now i follows that to some application for this modeling to use in Cryptography because convert plaintext to ciphertext needs to design an algorithm.

Do you have any information to help me?

Thanks,

Comment: I am sorry to say this, but your question is not clear... Try to define more precisely broad terms like *data*, *word*, etc.

Comment: Are you talking about the role of invertible permutations in cryptography? Like a P box? Like the permutation in PRESENT?

Comment: No, I will ask a better question.